# Javascript autocomplete dropdown function confusion

Tags: javascript, html

I am using [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp) W3C Schools autocomplete drop down.

```
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      /*for each item in the array...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
              b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
```

I am confused about this line of code in this autocomplete function:

```
inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
```

What is `this` referring to in the code above?

Why do we have to do `this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0]`?

I am getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

in this line. I did however modify the function above and removed the add event listener line on the `inp` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in below snippet the `this` keyword refer (inside handler) to input element itself. The author of the code use `this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0]` (however it is unclear why in this way) probably because he want to copy value from other input - however you can set that value without using it (e.g. in direct way `inp.value='some autocompleted vale'`, depends on your case)

```js
inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  console.log(this.value, this);
})
```

```html
<input id="inp" placeholder='type here'>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the code, you can find that while user start typing on input field a list appears with suggestions. And when the user clicks on anyone of the suggested option that value is being set to the textbox.

So here, in the suggested list the options are getting generated like this

`<div>
   <strong>A</strong>
   fghanistan
   <input type="hidden" value="Afghanistan">
</div>`

and we've click listener on this div element under that you can find this code

`this.getElementsByTagName` returns the collection of the element with the given tag name

code `this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0]` is searching for element with tag name `input` under `this` (which is current div).

`[0]` which is fist finding in returned collection so it finds input element with value `Afganistan`. Which is getting set to the textbox value.

Answer (score 0):

Lets break this question step by step.

1. You didn't copy the complete script from w3school, please copy it because there are few functions like "addEventListener", "addActive" etc related to to above code.
2. `inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;`
   here `this` reffers to document(window.document)
3. `this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0]`
   if we don't write it, we will get undefined, because here you are assigning that searched item to first element in searched input box.